# WinMLRunner: Extract ordered features from ONNX model

Tags: windows-machine-learning

Using WinMLRunner, I pass in an ONNX model (used Netron to see it i think). Then an image, the program runs in cmd, it shows out what follows:

```
Outputting top 5 values
Feature Name: pool5/7x7_s1
index: 661, value: 7.60391
index: 581, value: 7.41787
...
```

If the model features can be exported to a list, the index can be used to see what WinML is ranking.
Without extract features, WinMLRunning *works as a nice rng util ;)*

Answer (score 1):

the full tensor output can be output from winmlrunner into a csv file like this :

```
.\WinMLRunner.exe -model <path to model> -input <input path> -cpu -savetensordata first -periterationpath <desired directory path to output csv file>
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions.